# Why Direct3D application performs better in full screen mode?

Tags: performance, directx, fullscreen, direct3d

The performance of a Direct3D application seems to be significantly better in full screen mode compared to windowed mode. What are the technical reasons behind this?

I guess it has something to do with the fact that a full screen application can gain exclusive control for the display. But why the application cannot gain exclusive control for *part* of the screen (i.e. window) and have the same performance benefits?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try that on Vista? With DWM enabled, I experienced the window-mode speed to be rather higher on my system in an XNA application (higher because less fill-rate is needed, but the point is that it is not slower).

Comment: Yes I'm running Vista with DWM enabled. I also understand that Vista disables DWM when a full screen application is active to free resources.

Comment: Vista disables DWM only if the application is incompatible. I have some games running fine with Aero Glass when in Fullscreen (visible on the other monitors). Though in general that's true, most games disable DWM.

Comment: Since Windows 8 you can have your cake and eat it too with DirectFlip. Basically DWM detects if compositing would be a no-op and instead uses your framebuffer directly, giving you the same performance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here are the cliff notes on how things work underneath.

Monitor screen always needs to be associated with so-called primary surface to be able to display anything, i.e. videocard can only scan out of one surface in video memory.

When application is fullscreen (and everything was set up correctly to enable flipping), primary surface is just one of the application backbuffers, and flipped to another backbuffer every frame. It is the most efficient way of presenting on the screen, but it requires application to own the entire monitor area (i.e. entire primary surface).

When there's no fullscreen application and DWM is off, primary surface is owned by OS, and every windowed application performs a blit from application backbuffer to a primary surface. This blit takes some GPU time to complete (as well as blits from the other applications visible on the screen), so it's not as efficient as fullscreen presentation. XP worked that way.

When DWM is composing the screen, things get even more complicated.
Here, DWM owns the primary surface and needs to draw application windows there. To make it possible, every window has an associated surface holding its contents, called redirection surface (which allows DWM to enable window ghosting, glass effects, and all that good stuff). Every time D3D application issues a frame, it adds a blit to a redirection surface.
That way, several blits need to happen: blit to a redirection surface by the app, blit from a redirection surface to the primary by DWM, which is, again, some overhead compared to fullscreen.

Note all of that additional work is on the GPU, so it doesn't affect CPU performance.

Stuff to read further:

http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/archive/2006/03/19/555087.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/archive/2006/05/02/588934.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/archive/2006/03/05/544314.aspx

Comment: Thank you all for explanations! I think this answer summarizes the situation very well.

Answer (score 8):

There's [a bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205075(VS.85).aspx#Flipping) on MSDN that says full screen mode uses buffer flipping, if set up correctly, as opposed to blitting. It makes sense.

Of course you can (and in a way, do) give exclusive control for part of the screen to an application, but what happens to the rest of the screen? You still have to blit, do occlusion checking, etc. on the rest of the windows, and I think that's what causes the performance hit.

Comment: How would you give exclusive control for a part of the screen to an application? I'm hoping it will solve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357434/choppy-graphics-when-drawing-xna-on-a-winforms-control

Answer (score 5):

I'll add to @[aib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304669/why-direct3d-application-performs-better-in-full-screen-mode#304689)'s answer that the rest of the screen is being managed by the OS. So, if anything else needs to be drawn/worked upon simultaneously, there has to be a performance hit.

For example, if you have a video playing in Windows Media Player in one window, then start Civilization in another, when Civ starts doing its fancy graphics, it will need to share screen space with everything else (like the video.

Whereas if the DirectX app has the full-screen, everything else might be "updating" or "playing", but *not* being drawn.

Comment: Though your last sentence is only part of the game, if you think about multi-monitor setups.

Comment: I didn't state in my original post that I'm seeing this in Vista. If I've understood correctly, Vista with DWM enabled does window blitting in hardware. I can't come up with any better suggestion than aib's and yours, but it puzzles me if this extra blitting can slow things down so much.

Comment: fair enough, @OregonGhost... I was trying to keep it simple, though :)

Comment: @smt: What can actually slow down things is that in Vista, a 3D device is a shared resource, so there is no full control over it by a single app (in an ideal world).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the video hardware is completely dedicated to the exclusive mode application.

There is no contention for video resources (pipeline, texture memory, etc...)

In particular, texture upload can be a big bottleneck. The less you have to do it (because you have it all), the better.