# Windowed mode framerate vs Full screen framerate

Tags: c#, performance, xna

I'm developping an XNA game and I usually start my application in windowed mode for debug purposes. For strange reasons, my application is 50% slower in windowed mode than in fullscreen mode.

Can someone tell me why and how the windowed mode affects the framerate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304669/why-direct3d-application-performs-better-in-full-screen-mode). The guy explains clearly why this behavior happens.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I narrowed my search to XNA and skipped that post!